# How can I recreate this query in ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know this sounds like a "do my homework for me" question, but I've been struggling with recreating this query with ActiveRecord for a while and am now wondering if it's possible to do this without resorting to using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`

The structure is basically:

`Member has_many orders and transactions`

I need to display all the members who have placed an order, the total amount from orders, and the number of transactions for a given date range ordered by the total amount.

I can get the data I need with the following query:

```
SELECT members.*,
SUM(orders.amount) AS total_amount,
COUNT(transactions.id) AS total_transactions 
FROM members 
INNER JOIN orders ON (orders.member_id = member.id) 
LEFT JOIN transactions ON (transactions.member_id = members.id)
WHERE orders.created_at BETWEEN "2012-03-01" AND "2012-04-01" 
GROUP BY member.id 
ORDER BY total_amount DESC
```

Is it possible to formulate this query via ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd do it through ActiveRecord:

```
Member.includes(:orders, :transactions).select("SUM(orders.amount) as total_amount").where("orders.created_at BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-04-01'").group('members.id').order('total_amount DESC')
```

This includes a lot of raw SQL snippets. If you want to replace those with actual Ruby code you can do that by using Member.arel_table creatively. See [the Arel documentation](https://github.com/rails/arel) for information on how to do that.